# How do I specialize templates across different modules?

Tags: d

```
module a;
void foo(T)(){
    import std.stdio;
    writeln(T.stringof);
}

module b;
import a;

private alias foo = a.foo;
void foo(T: int)(){
    import std.stdio;
    writeln("Special int");
}
//app.d
void main()
{
    import a;
    import b;
    foo!int();
}
```

This prints `int` instead of `Special Int`. Is it possible to specialize templates across different modules?

Can I assume that the answer to [D template specialization in different source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362280/d-template-specialization-in-different-source-file?rq=1) is still relevant today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alias is wrong and your import introduces ambiguities. If you want it publicly overloadable, don't make the alias private!

Once the alias is made public (the default btw), compiling this will spit out a name conflict error:

```
iii.d(6): Error: a.foo(T)() at ii.d(2) conflicts with b.foo at i.d
```

Then, it is a simple matter of disambiguating (specifying `b.foo!int()`), or better yet, removing the unnecessary `import a` from the usage point.

```
//app.d
void main()
{
    import b;
    foo!int();
}
```

Special int!

For more complex cases, you can also make a wrapper for the template and forward your arguments, but here the simple alias overloading - when done with `alias foo = a.foo;`, no `private`, will do the trick.